# Program recurs in different line than supposed to

Tags: recursion, prolog, logic

I have some rules called sessions that have a Title(String) and Topics (a list of String). I'm creating a query where I input some keywords and find which session has a best match. Each keyword can have a weight (keyword is followed by -2 for example if weight of keyword is 2, if weight is 1 there is nothing next to the keyword). 
My problem is in the recursion. For inputs without weights everything is ok but with weights the program recurs differently.

```
session('Rules; Semantic Technology; and Cross-Industry Standards',
['XBRL - Extensible Business Reporting Language',
 'MISMO - Mortgage Industry Standards Maintenance Org',
 'FIXatdl - FIX Algorithmic Trading Definition Language',
 'FpML - Financial products Markup Language',
 'HL7 - Health Level 7',
 'Acord - Association for Cooperative Operations Research and Development (Insurance Industry)',
 'Rules for Governance; Risk; and Compliance (GRC); eg; rules for internal audit; SOX compliance; enterprise risk management (ERM); operational risk; etc',
 'Rules and Corporate Actions']).

session('Rule Transformation and Extraction',
['Transformation and extraction with rule standards; such as SBVR; RIF and OCL',
 'Extraction of rules from code',
 'Transformation and extraction in the context of frameworks such as KDM (Knowledge Discovery meta-model)',
 'Extraction of rules from natural language',
 'Transformation or rules from one dialect into another']).

accessList([H|T], H, T).

is_empty_string(String) :-
    String == ''.
not_empty_string(String) :-
    String \== ''.

get_weight_of_token(MyToken, WeightOfToken) :-
    split_string(MyToken,"-","",TempList),  % tokenize MyToken into a list ( [string_of_token, weight_of_token] ) 
    accessList(TempList,_,TempWeight),          %
    accessList(TempWeight,TempWeight2,_),       % accessing the tail of the list (weight_of_token)
    number_string(WeightOfToken,TempWeight2)    % convert string to number

    ;

    WeightOfToken is 1.

find_relevance([], SessionTitle, SessionTopics).
find_relevance([H | T], SessionTitle, SessionTopics) :-
    get_weight_of_token(H, WeightOfToken),
    format('Token = ~w with weight = ~d ~n', [H,WeightOfToken]),
    format('Title = ~w~nTopics = ~w ~n', [SessionTitle,SessionTopics]),
    find_relevance(T, SessionTitle, SessionTopics).

query(ListOfKeywords) :-
    is_empty_string(ListOfKeywords), write('List of keywords is empty!')

    ;

    not_empty_string(ListOfKeywords),
    split_string(ListOfKeywords," ","",KeywordsTokens),     %tokenize string with space as separator
    session(Title,Topics), find_relevance(KeywordsTokens, Title, Topics), fail.
```

With an input without weights like 'firword secword', this is the result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCFps.jpg

As you can see the program recurs fine and calls find_revelance for the next session.

With an input with weights like 'firword-2 secword', this is the result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WTD8.jpg

As you can see the program doesn't recur to (9) for the next session but recurs to (10) for some reason.. and specifically to the part after ;..

Why is this happening? Thanks in advance.

*I changed the titles and topics to something smaller so the images can be more clear